# ¿Existe un adjetivo para aquello relacionado al género?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Para determinados sustantivos existe un adjetivo terminado en -al que significa "relacionado a x sustantivo". Por ejemplo,

Lo relacionado a una persona es personal,

Lo relacionado a un individuo es individual,

Lo relacionado al comercio es comercial,

etc.

¿Existe un adjetivo para aquello relacionado al género en el sentido de (hombre/mujer),
(no en el sentido de género de las palabras u otro significado)?

Comment: [genérico](https://dle.rae.es/genérico): _4. adj. Gram. Perteneciente o relativo al género._ Paradójico, que la palabra "genérico" sea demasiado específica en este caso, solo para gramática, cuando la quisiéramos... genérica :P

Comment: @fedorqui busqué la definición en Inglés de generic (genérico), dice "relativo a una clase o grupo de cosas (personas incluidas tal vez?), no específico". Curiosamente la primera definición de género (gender) era "tipo o clase de personas que comparten una característica común". Será que sí se puede usar como relativo a hombre/mujer aunque no sea de uso común?

Comment: Sí, eso me parece a mí, aunque la RAE lo marca como propio solamente de la Gramática. De ahí mi juego de palabras diciendo que sí puede ser usado para querer decir lo que buscas, pero que sin más contexto no creo que se pueda entender en este sentido.

Comment: I think _generic_ in English is mostly used for things rather than people but it would be understood. It dos not usually have anything much to do with grammatical gender or biological sex. Not sure if that helps with the Spanish word.

Comment: género means gender. And there is no adjective in Spanish associated with it. Unless you say: de género masculino o de género femenino génerico is the adjective for gender in grammar only.

Answer (score 2):

¿Podría ser **sexo**?

> 1. m. Condición orgánica, masculina o femenina, de los animales y las plantas.
> 2. m. Conjunto de seres pertenecientes a un mismo sexo. *Sexo masculino, femenino.*

Pero como lo que solicitas es el adjetivo, entonces ¿podría ser **sexual**?

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al sexo.

Comment: Justamente quería evitar la palabra sexual porque se puede interpretar de dos maneras, como relacionado al género, o como relacionado al acto sexual. Pero supongo que en los términos que está hecha la pregunta la respuesta es correcta, aunque no la deseada

Comment: Tuve las mismas dudas que tú, y esto es lo que creo que más se aproxima.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si dijeras "enfermedad sexual", la gente pensaría que es una enfermedad relacionada con tener relaciones sexuales, y no con la condición de ser biológicamente hombre o mujer

Answer (score 0):

Tradicionalmente el género es lo que determina al hombre y a la mujer, como masculino o femenino y a partir de ahí, con sus excepciones, se extiende al resto de palabras.

En Español actual solo cabe referirse al género como masculino o femenino, ya que solo se atiende a estos dos conceptos. Sin embargo la RAE, normalmente, va por detrás de lo que al tiempo ocurre en la propia sociedad y en este caso el lenguaje que esta utiliza.

Actualmente se habla de "**lenguaje inclusivo**" o simplemente "inclusivo" para referirse al género, con ello se pretende la no discriminación, hombre/mujer. A este respecto, hay que tener en cuenta que la RAE, no admite este lenguaje.

Si buscas algo más allá de hombre/mujer, teóricamente también inclusivo, aquello que califica un tipo de "percepción personal" se puede utilizar el término "**identidad de género**",  voz "gender identity" acuñada desde 1964, a partir del psiquiatra R. Stoller, para diferenciar "el género" y "el sexo", y que en su evolución incluye no solo a hombres o mujeres, sino a cualquier otro tipo de género, utilizándose para "describir" a su vez otras tipologías "asignadas", ya que se puede mal interpretar y cualquiera de ellas puede sentirse discriminada;

- Queer
- Género Fluido
- Sin Género
- Bigénero
- Intergénero
- Cisgénero
- ... actualmente hasta 33 géneros

Otra fórmula utilizada es "Orientación Sexual" y "Rol de Género", que estarían dentro del mismo rango expuesto más arriba.

*Identidad de Género*

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identidad_de_g%C3%A9nero

---

P.D. Otros adjetivos;

- Adj. "Dual" - (dualismo de género)
- Adj. "Binario" - (binarismo, binariedad, binariedad de género )
- Adj. "Genérico" - Que es general, se refiere a elementos del mismo género. Por ejem. la voz "persona", es genérico, ya que alude a ellas independientemente de su raza o sexo.
- Adj. "Genital" - (También puede actuar como sustantivo).
- Adj. "Genitivo - va" Que puede engendrar y producir algo.

Comment: Esto no tiene ninguna relación con la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que, la asesora profesional avanzada, Noemí Marciali, de Coordinadora de Equidad, Géneros y DDHH del INAES, utiliza para ello el término "Géneros", pero no me pareció el más apropiado, aunque también puedes probar con "diverso", en el sentido de distinta naturaleza ó incluso con el de "desigual". Saludos.

Comment: de nuevo, no entiendes la pregunta. "diverso" y "desigual", no significan "relacionado al género". "Géneros" no es un adjetivo.

Comment: Bueno, "diverso" y "desigual", si son adjetivos, también lo es "dual", que puede actuar tanto de sustantivo como de adjetivo.  Si una persona es individual, en este caso, dos personas, hombre/mujer, puede también ser ó actuar algo "dual". Solo intento ayudar, perdón si meto la pata. Lo siento. No es mi intención.